# ADF strange execution behaviour

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that loops over 4k times and does something. 
Yesterday i cancel triggered pipeline after 2k executions, and I see in today's execution i have some pipelines that are executed with parameters from yesterday.

To explain, in my trigger definition i have formatDateTime(trigger().scheduledTime,'dd') for day parameter, and today (05) i see that some of the pipelines have day parameter=04 even their run start time is today.

Could it be some of the execution were stuck somewhere and with today's trigger they were just activated with parameters from yesterday?

Additional: Why I think 2k executions from yesterday was stuck (somewhere): I define 4 parallel executions, and there were 8 in the same moment.

Additional: to describe mess with parameters, same parameter is used for folder structure and for filename structure, and there is scenario like this:

folder/system/2019/06/**04**/filename_2019_06_**05**

Comment: Is this timezone related?  I think trigger scheduled time is in UTC and the run start time may be displayed by the UI in local time.  This doesn't explain why if your folder and file date would be different if they were derived from the same "day" parameter.

Note - if you have stuck pipelines, there was a recent fix to the integration runtime to clear such a bug (if you are self hosted - shared has already been updated).

Comment: @MarkD no its not timezone related, it seems I did not cancel this pipeline on a proper way. 
Tbh i did not get any response from ADF team whatsoever, and I submitted feedback. 
If you want to cancel something do it from Monitoring screen